# Integration testing with Junit

Tags: junit, integration-testing

I have a million requests and responses in a mongo collection. I have written a parameterized JUnit to load the request and run it against another server and compare the response with the mongo collection response.

The issue is, this is a good solution for a few 1000 documents in collection, but is not a scalable solution.

Is there any suggestion or good api which extends JUNit to help me test a million records. 
Also, I would like to have each of the record to be a unit test case, so that it shows finally how many has passed.

Here is a snippet using Junit5 :

```
@TestFactory
Stream<DynamicTest> test1() throws Exception {
    List<MyClass> data = setUp();
    return data.stream().map(d -> DynamicTest.dynamicTest("TC"+d.toString(), () -> assertTrue(doTest(d))));
}

public boolean doTest(MyClass mc) {
//actual test
}
```

Issue with this code is this line

```
 List<MyClass> data = setUp();
```

It tries to load all the testcase from the mongo and I am not sure how to split this up. Let me know if a Junit4 way of code is needed.

Comment: Why is it not scalable?

Comment: This sounds like it is about performance tests. If it is, there are test frameworks like JMeter that are designed to cover this kind of tests.

Comment: These aren't performance tests. There are some legacy systems for which we have been caching results to understand their behavior. There are about million test cases.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind The current unit tests force me to load all the data in setUp or even the junit5 Dynamic tests force me to load the data and then run the tests. This is clearly not scalable. I would prefer it to load about x test cases at a time and continue on them until million is done. I don't know a way to do that now.

Comment: maybe you could add some example as I cannot imagine why you can't load only partial data or split it in multiple testcases. I wrote a data loader once that loaded the data just before the test case was run.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind Please check updated post